# Matlab copyfile file to file not working

Tags: matlab, rename, file-copying

I want to make a copy of a source file in a directory and paste it in the SAME directory but under a different name. I want to loop over a number of participants. The name of the source file varies across participants (though it always has the same onset).

I've written the following loop:

```
file_root = '/pathtofile/';
sourcefile = 'ABCDE.nii';
destinationfile = 'FGHIJ.nii';

for s = 1:length(subjects) % loops over subjects
    copyfile([file_root subjects{s} '/' 'stats' '/' sourcefile], [file_root subjects{s} '/' 'stats' '/' destinationfile]);
end
```

This loop works fine for the subset of subjects that have the same source file name and it correctly generates the destination file in the SAME directory as the source file.

Now, when I include a wildcard in the source file to deal with varying names in the source files, the loop still works but it generates a new directory called destinationfile which contains a copy of sourcefile (with the same name). So, for example:

```
file_root = '/pathtofile/';
sourcefile = 'ABCD*.img';
destinationfile = 'FGHIJ.img';

for s = 1:length(subjects) % loops over subjects
    copyfile([file_root subjects{s} '/' 'stats' '/' sourcefile], [file_root subjects{s} '/' 'stats' '/' destinationfile]);
end
```

This loop generates a new directory 'FGHIJ.img' containing the 'ABCDE.img" file within the 'file_root' directory.

So my question is this: how can I use copyfile(source, destination) with a wildcard in the source, which generates a new destination FILE in the same directory.

I hope this makes sense. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Wildcard character, `copyfile` assumes you are copying multiple files to a folder, thus interpreting the destination as a directory. You can not use wildcards and set a target file. Use the `dir` command to get the matching file name.

I also recommend to use `fullfile` to concatenate file path because it is more robust

```
file_root = '/pathtofile/';
sourcefile = 'ABCD*.img';
destinationfile = 'FGHIJ.img';

for s = 1:length(subjects) % loops over subjects
    source_pattern=fullfile(file_root subjects{s} , 'stats' , sourcefile);
    matching_files=dir(source_pattern);
    source_file=fullfile(file_root subjects{s} , 'stats' , matching_files(1).name);
    target_file=fullfile(file_root subjects{s} , 'stats' , destinationfile)
    copyfile(source_file, target_file);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes sense although copyfile does not recognize *.img to represent a wildcard the way you imagine it to.

A better approach of doing this (maybe not the best, but what I would do) is  generate a list of files within the directory, which can use the * wildcard:

```
file_root = '/pathtofile/';

for s = 1:length(subjects) % loops over subjects
   %create the directory for this subject
   subject_dir = fullfile(file_root,subjects{s},'stats');

   %get a struct of the .img files beginning with ABCD with the dir command
   subject_sources = dir(subject_dir,'ABCD*.img');

   %loop through the source files and copy them
   for fidx = 1:length(subject_sources)
       source_fname = subject_sources(fidx).name;

       %of course you can add lines to format/create a proper
       %destination file name. strtok, strsplit, regexp...
       dest_fname = ['FGHIJ' s(5:end)];

       copyfile(fullfile(subject_dir,source_fname),...
       fullfile(subject_dir,dest_fname)
   end
end
```